# Binding against Image source property

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I need to binding to image.source property.

this works obviusly:

```
<Image Source="/Intecsal.Generico.Recursos;component/Images/Flags/ES.png"/>
```

but, I have a var with the string "ES" and I want to do something like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding var, StringFormat=/Intecsal.Generico.Recursos;component/Images/Flags/{0}.png}"/>
```

But this doesn't work.. the image is not shown.

Can someone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt work that way. Source property has the type  ImageSource and every string being passed through Binding will be converter to new  ImageSource instance. Binding has internally many converters.

That is the reason why your StringFormat has no effect at all and it never will :)

However, you still have the option to use Converter in Binding that will convert your properties value into whatever you wish :)

Take a look at this code line:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Whatever, 
                        Converter={StaticResource WhateverToSourceConverter}"/>
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by adding a sample implementation of the converter. You might then also show the proper usage of pack URIs in code behind, and how you would create a BitmapImage from such a URI.

Comment: @Clemens You are right.. Though, lets hope OP knows how to use google :) :)

Comment: No code available right now. I just typed that one liner. Not sure if I spelled everything right.